# WPF DataGrid style

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid with the following style

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridRowStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFB3B3B3"/>
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DataGridRowControlTemplate1}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF262626"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF383838"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and it appears like this:

[image]

My problem appears when the DataGrid lose the focus:

[image]

How can I make it's appearance independent of the focus ?

Comment: can you share the completed full xaml style? Looks like nice.

Comment: Can I ask which font you are using?

Comment: I can't remember, sorry

Comment: @Dan Sewell, It looks like Nina, microsoft's narrow version of Verdana. http://www.identifont.com/similar?EL4

Comment: Very nice style! Can you post the xaml style?

Comment: @MarcoConcas Unfortunately I don't have access to it anymore! sorry.

Comment: @MarcoConcas Nice isn't it! Just was thinking that aha

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before you try to find a solution, look in your `Style/Template` of DataGrid, DataGridRow, etc. a StyleTrigger on Focus (`IsFocused` trigger), because it can not be the default behavior.

If do not have one, try to add `EvenTriggers` for events [`GotFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.gotfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`LostFocus`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.lostfocus%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="GotFocusColor" Color="Green" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="LostFocusColor" Color="Transparent" />

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FFB3B3B3"/>
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF262626"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="0">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF383838"/>
            </Trigger>

            <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.AlternationIndex" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF333333"/>
            </Trigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.GotFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource GotFocusColor}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>

            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="DataGrid.LostFocus">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{StaticResource LostFocusColor}" />
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

Comment: one on team should test your solution and give me a feedback!! sorry for the postponement.

Comment: @m.samy: My answer helped you, or do you have questions?

Comment: Thanks this work for a datagrid inside WPF MUI App but just changed the Windows.Resource to UserControl.Resource as this was inside a UserControl